# Remove the gap of element in CSS grid carousel when scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, css-grid

I've created a carousel in JS. but i'm having a CSS problem. when I scroll to next element I have the grid gap which I set but it's disturbing the last image's width. in image you can see in left side i have the grid. but i can't just remove the gap it would go for all grid items. so can you please help me with this problem. where after scrolling just the first grid element's gap get removed. or some way to achieve what I want. Thank You.
***The image is of after scrolling***. at first everything is ok.

[image: left side gap which I want to remove]

```css
.carousel-content {
  display: grid;
  --grid-column-gap: 15px;
  --grid-rows: 1;
  grid-auto-columns: calc((100% - 5 * var(--grid-column-gap))/ 6);
  grid-column-gap: var(--grid-column-gap);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  transition: all 400ms linear;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-content" style="transform: translateX(-100%);">
  <div class="grid-item" data-item-index="1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="placeholder" style="width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" data-item-index="2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="placeholder" style="width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" data-item-index="3">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="placeholder" style="width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" data-item-index="4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="placeholder" style="width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" data-item-index="5">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="placeholder" style="width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" data-item-index="6">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="placeholder" style="width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" data-item-index="7">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="placeholder" style="width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" data-item-index="8">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="placeholder" style="width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" data-item-index="9">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="placeholder" style="width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" data-item-index="10">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="placeholder" style="width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" data-item-index="11">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="placeholder" style="width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" data-item-index="12">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="placeholder" style="width: 100%;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding some `margin` and `padding` to each item with class of `grid-item`

Comment: @pradhuman, can you provide a working example

Comment: thank you @NisanthReddy but problem solved. by removing the grid gap and adding both side margins to each element.

Comment: Thank You so much @michael.grigoryan. setting margins worked.